# Groovy Script to read and transform xml

Tags: xml, groovy, transformation

Need help on Groovy Script. I have the following input xml where this xml will be dynamically populated and we do not have any clues on how many nodes will be populated under `RecordDetails` Node.

**Input:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Record>
   <XYZ>
      <Header>
         <Code>12345</Code>
      </Header>
      <Details>
         <RecID>1</RecID>
         <RecordDetail>
            <Name>ABC</Name>
            <Email>abc@in.com</Email>
            <Address>123,acdf</Address>
         </RecordDetail>
      </Details>
      <Details>
         <RecID>2</RecID>
         <RecordDetail>
            <Name>ABC</Name>
            <Email>abc@in.com</Email>
         </RecordDetail>
      </Details>
   </XYZ>
</Record>
```

**Output:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Record>
   <Header>
      <Code>12345</Code>
   </Header>
   <Details>
      <RecID>1</RecID>
      <RecordDetail>
         <FieldName>NAME</FieldName>
         <FieldValue>ABC</FieldValue>
      </RecordDetail>
      <RecordDetail>
         <FieldName>Email</FieldName>
         <FieldValue>ABC@a.com</FieldValue>
      </RecordDetail>
   </Details>
</Record>
```

Comment: Input XMl:

<xml...
<Record>
 <XYZ>
  <Header>
   <Code>12345</Code>
  </Header>
  <Details>
   <RecID>1</RecID>
   <RecordDetail>
     <Name>ABC</Name>
     <Email>abc@in.com</Email>
     <Address>123,acdf</Address>
   </RecordDetail>
  </Details>
  <Details>
   <RecID>2</RecID>
   <RecordDetail>
     <Name>ABC</Name>
     <Email>abc@in.com</Email>
   </RecordDetail>
  </Details>
 </XYZ>
</Record>

Comment: Output XML:
<Record>
 <Header>
   <Code>12345</Code>
 </Header>
 <Details>
   <RecID>1</RecID>
   <RecordDetail>>
     <FieldName>NAME</FieldName>
     <FieldValue>ABC</FieldValue>
   </RecordDetail>
   <RecordDetail>>
     <FieldName>Email</FieldName>
     <FieldValue>ABC@a.com</FieldValue>
    </RecordDetail>
 </Details>
</Record>

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't post soure code as comment, add it to the question. And what have you tried so far? Can you add some source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to transform the input xml.

This can be achieved by:

- write an xslt and use runner to execute
- transform in groovy itself.

Looks like you are looking for the later one.

Here is the groovy script:

```groovy
def xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Record>
   <XYZ>
      <Header>
         <Code>12345</Code>
      </Header>
      <Details>
         <RecID>1</RecID>
         <RecordDetail>
            <Name>ABC</Name>
            <Email>abc@in.com</Email>
            <Address>123,acdf</Address>
         </RecordDetail>
      </Details>
      <Details>
         <RecID>2</RecID>
         <RecordDetail>
            <Name>ABC</Name>
            <Email>abc@in.com</Email>
         </RecordDetail>
      </Details>
   </XYZ>
</Record>'''

def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

def builder = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder()
builder.encoding = 'UTF-8'
def transformedXml = builder.bind {
    mkp.xmlDeclaration() 
    Record {
        Header {
            Code (parsedXml.'**'.find{ it.name() == 'Code'})
        }
        def details = parsedXml.'**'.findAll{ it.name() == 'Details'}       
        details.each { detail ->
            Details {
                RecID (detail.RecID)
                detail.RecordDetail.children().each { fld ->
                    RecordDetail { 
                        FieldName (fld.name())
                        FieldValue (fld.text())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(transformedXml)
```

This can be quickly tried online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5192414738251776)</kbd>

**Output:**

[image]

**EDIT:** Based on the OP's questions.

`mkp.xmlDeclaration()` - adds `<?xml version="1.0"?>`

`details.each { detail ->` - details is list. We want to loop thru the each detail. Each value goes into `detail`.

Just similar to `for(detail : details)`.

`fld` is also the same as above.

Comment: Hi @Rao, Thanks for this answer, Im facing dfficulty in reading xml file with a different format like <Header code='12345' />. COuld u please help me to read the code from this header.